# $geoNear no result from near coordinates

Tags: mongodb

I have a very strange behavior when aggregating results in MongoDB. For example, if I query the following :

```
db.getCollection('locations').aggregate([
{"$geoNear": {
    "spherical": true,
    "maxDistance": 14239,
    "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [45.180584858570136,5.760955810546876]
    },
    "distanceField": "distance"
}},
{"$match": {
    "datetime": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2019-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2019-03-02T00:00:00Z")
    }
}}
])
```

I get no results. But if I change the coordinates to `[45.180584858570136,5.7602691650390625]` which is 53.82 meters away from the first point, I get 16 results like this one :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c791c276bc27675f3bd2d7f"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5c4620c96bc27618b1a39cfe"),
    "coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            45.1837952, 
            5.7204736
        ]
    },
    "datetime" : ISODate("2019-03-01T11:37:04.000Z"),
    "_updated" : ISODate("2019-03-01T11:48:55.000Z"),
    "_created" : ISODate("2019-03-01T11:48:55.000Z"),
    "_etag" : "535e09d3d25f0b970fef8e45f220e41a99fd11f6",
    "distance" : 4444.24394629098
}
```

Well, I can't understand why I get no results in the first case, because all the 16 results must match the given range...

Here's a more complete sample of data : https://gist.github.com/sylvainbx/502515b809341173e0ee36d4579ba31b

Does anyone has already saw this before or has any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You should show some more data with enough to reproduce your claimed result. For me, the supplied document returns with a `distance` within the `maxDistance` setting for both sets of coordinates.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution by myself. Changing the query as the following fixes the issue:

```
db.getCollection('locations').aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [45.180584858570136,5.760955810546876] },
        key: "coordinates",
        spherical: true,
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: 14239,
        query: { 
            "datetime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2019-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2019-03-02T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
     }
   }
])
```